# How to remove click tracking in Adobe Analytics

Tags: javascript, adobe, tracking, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to remove default click tracking in Adobe Analytics? We want all our tracking by having full control of what is being sent to the Adobe Servers by using the `s.tl()` function manually.

I have tried setting `window.s.stackInlineStats` to `false` as described in [the documentation](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/oms_sc_implement.pdf), but it still keeps tracking any link clicks.

Is there any way of disabling default click tracking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I *assume* you typo'd and meant `trackInlineStats` but I'm mentioning it just in case you didn't:  `stackInlineStats` is not a native Adobe Analytics variable used by the library. You may have custom code that uses this (arbitrary) property, and if that is the case, you will need to provide relevant code that utilizes it, so we can better understand what it does.

Under the assumption you typo'd and meant [`trackInlineStats`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/trackInlineStats.html) : this is for Adobe Analytics legacy clickmap tracking. You should definitely remove that property from your code (or set it to `false`). It has been buggy for years, often causing issues with tracking (including causing the entire tracking request to be rejected by Adobe servers, in some cases). But even then, the reporting for it wasn't great. Adobe has a (relatively) newer module called Activity Map if you want "heat map" type tracking from Adobe Analytics (it sounds like you don't).

On that note.. if you are using the latest AppMeasurement library, you will need to remove the [Activity Map](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/analytics/activitymap/activitymap-sample-implementation-code.html) module that comes with it. If you are downloading the library from the code manager in the AA interface, it's the smaller chunk of code that comes in the s_code.js, above the main library. All you have to do is remove that from your s_code.js file. If you are implementing AA through DTM and have AA library setup to be "Managed by Adobe", then you will need to switch it to "Custom" (you manage it yourself) so you can remove the Activity Module (sidenote: you lose the benefits of "Managed by Adobe" - for whatever reason, DTM does not currently give you an option to disable Activity Map if you choose to have AA be managed by Adobe).

In addition to this, you will also want to set the following variables to `false`:

[`trackDownloadLinks`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/trackDownloadLinks.html) - This is for automatically tracking download links. It will cause the AA library to trigger an `s.tl` call on links that end in file types such as `.pdf` (whatever you list in `linkDownloadFileTypes`)

[`trackExternaLinks`](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/trackExternalLinks.html) - This is for automatically tracking exit links. It will cause the AA library to trigger an `s.tl` call on links that don't match against `linkInternalFilters` vs. `linkExternalFilters`

If you have AA implemented as a tool in DTM, the equivalent of these two variables are in the AA tool config > Link Tracking section. Make sure **Track Download Links** and **Track Outbound Links** are both disabled (uncheck the checkbox)